# emitting from thread using flask's socketio extension

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I want to emit a delayed message to a socket client. For example, when a new client connects, "checking is started" message should be emitted to the client, and after a certain seconds another message from a thread should be emitted.

```
@socket.on('doSomething', namespace='/test')
def onDoSomething(data):
  t = threading.Timer(4, checkSomeResources)
  t.start()
  emit('doingSomething', 'checking is started')

def checkSomeResources()
  # ...
  # some work which takes several seconds comes here
  # ...
  emit('doingSomething', 'checking is done')
```

But the code does not work because of context issue. I get

```
RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
```

Is it possible to make emitting from a thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the thread does not have the context to know what user to address the message to.

You can pass `request.namespace` to the thread as an argument, and then send the message with it. Example:

```
@socket.on('doSomething', namespace='/test')
def onDoSomething(data):
    t = threading.Timer(4, checkSomeResources, request.namespace)
    t.start()
    emit('doingSomething', 'checking is started')

def checkSomeResources(namespace)
    # ...
    # some work which takes several seconds comes here
    # ...
    namespace.emit('doingSomething', 'checking is done')
```

Comment: I think this answer will still fail if you have long running threads. See my answer below.

Comment: This did fail for me. request.namespace is a string, which does not have an emit method. I've tried socketio.emit('doingSomething', namespace=request.namespace), but that's not working with class based Namespace either. Still stuck!

Comment: Note the date on this answer. This is valid for a very old version. See the example application on the Flask-SocketIO repository on GitHub for a more recent example.